# sp_columns or information_schema.columns

Tags: sql-server, multiple-columns

What is the real benefit/difference of using sp_columns versus information_schema.columns?

They return some slightly different data, and it looks like information_schema is more likley to be of use to me, but I was wondering if anybody has experience of the benefits/disbenefits of each approach.

This could also cover sp_tables versus information_schema.tables as well I guess, the same thing applies right?

Answer (score 1):

The information schema is defined in the SQL standard and can therefore be expected to be portable and remain stable. I would go for using the information_schema.columns view.

Comment: Right, portability seemed to be the main reason when I was thinking about it. I just wanted to be sure. Thanks